# I want an iOS app which communicates to another app in PC/MAC via USB

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, usb

I want an iOS app which communicates to **another app** in PC/MAC via **USB**.,Is there any way to do it **without** jailbreaking the iOS device and **without** applying to **Apple's MFI** Program ?
I don't intend to submit the application to Appstore.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Not really. If you don't want to go the official way, you need to jailbreak. Or just use the headphone out and a modem :D

Comment: ok, thats what I thought, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [External Accessory Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/index.html)